# Why is my Vuex state not changing after nuxtServerInit commit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, contentful

I've been using `nuxtServerInit` to fetch data from my contenful CMS and commit the mutation to add the data to the categories state object. However categories keeps showing empty, even when I try to render it on a component.

I can `console.log` the data in the mutation function and see the data, why isn't it being pushed into the categories state?

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import {createClient} from '~/plugins/contentful.js' //contentful plugin function

const client = createClient()
const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      categories: {}
    },
    mutations: {
      addCategories(state, data) {
        state.categories += data.items
      }
    },
    actions: {
      async nuxtServerInit(context) {
        client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'category' //fetch everything with the content type set to category
          })
          .then(response => context.commit('addCategories', response))
          .catch(console.error)
      }
    },
  })
}

export default createStore
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import { createClient } from '~/plugins/contentful'

const client = createClient()

export default = () => new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: {}
  },

  mutations: {
    addCategories (state, data) {
      Vue.$set(state, 'categories', [...data.items, ...state.catagories])
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {    
      let response

      try {
        response = await client.getEntries({ content_type: 'category' })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }

      context.commit('addCategories', response)
    },
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate. However all i needed was your promise in the actions part. also, it needed to be just commit. not context.commit. Thanks Again

Comment: A little explanation on how two codes differ would have been helpful